# How to parse ~{expr} inside string with lark ebnf

Tags: python, regex, parsing, ebnf, lark-parser

I am trying to write a lark grammar for a dsl, but having trouble with this string interpolation syntax:

```
" abc " <- normal string
" xyz~{expression}abc " <- string with interpolation
```

so a ~{ switches from string to expression, and a } terminates that expression. I think this is close:

```
string : "\"" (string_interp|not_string_interp)* "\""
string_interp: "~{" expression "}"
not_string_interp: /([^~][^{])+/
```

But the regex will only match even numbers of characters, and if the ~{ straddles an even boundary, it will be missed.

```
not_string_interp: /(.?|([^~][^{])+)/
```

This is about as far as I could get, but still seems wrong. Can I use lookaheads? I also want to keep %ignore WS on, as it keeps the noise down massively, so a solution accounting for that would be great!

Thanks

Test cases:

```
""
"a"
"~{1}"
" ~{1} "
"a bc~{1}c d"
"a b~{1}c d"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does it. Sadly any ~ not followed by { will split the string up, but I can reconstruct them later. I am getting fooled by the equal precedence of rules, and the greediness of regexes.

`/[^"~]+/` anything that is not ~ or " (regular string)

`"~{" expression "}"` the normal expression

`/~(?!{)/` handle ~ without {. Use ?! because we must not consume next char (it could be " or another ~)

```
from lark import Lark

print (Lark(r"""
    string: "\"" string_thing* "\""
    string_thing: /[^"~]+/
        | "~{" expression "}"
        | /~(?!{)/
    expression: /[^}]+/
""", start='string', ambiguity="explicit").parse(
# '"a"'
'"a~b{}c}d~{1}g"'
# '"~abc~"'
# '"~{1}~~{1}~~~{1}"'
).pretty())
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a solution to your problem](https://regex101.com/r/lcm3xL/2) using a positive lookbehind.

`(?<=~{)[^}]+`

It looks for the beginning of the expression `~{` and captures everything until the closing brace `}`

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure where I should put the regex. Also how will a lookbehind interact with other ebnf rules? I do not know

Comment: I'm not familiar with ebnf so I can't say for sure. As far as where to put the regex goes, try something like this. `Regex.Matches("(?<=~{)[^}]+", allofyourtext)`